# Wireless Stopped working after 3.2.0-25 upgrade

Tags: wireless, drivers, command-line, kernel

Today, I downloaded the 3.2.0-25 kernel as suggested by Software Update.

After restart, my wireless isn't working, doesn't even show up in the Network Manager.

If during boot, I choose the previous kernel 3.2.0-24, everything is hunky dory

My machine is an HP h9xt with a RT5390STA wireless card.

Andrew

Comment: Which version of **Ubuntu**?  12.04 ?

Comment: I have same problem at the last time, but I can solved it by directly download the driver from www.ralinktech.com. Don't use the driver from the CD. May be it have been expired.
And I use this [site](http://steveswinsburg.wordpress.com/2011/03/12/how-to-install-a-d-link-dwa-525-wireless-network-card-in-ubuntu-10-04) for my case.

Comment: Thanks izx, your guide has helped resolve an issue with my Asus X54C laptop. It has an Ralink RT5390 network card but was using the wrong driver resulting in very slow network speeds and constant network drop-outs. I had to make a change to the config.mk settings that you specified: HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT appears to have been renamed to HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT - the following command work: Change the WPA2 variable: WPA2=HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT I also had to blacklist the rt2800pci driver and then reboot: echo "blacklist rt2800pci" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to rebuild the driver module for your card. Here's how:

- Your adapter has a Ralink RT5390 chipset. You can download the official Linux drivers from [this site](http://www.ralinktech.com/en/04_support/license.php?sn=5001). Save them to your Downloads folder (default):

  [image]
- Open a terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-T`, and paste the following, line by line:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential
  cd Downloads
  tar -xjf 2011_0406_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO_GPL.bz2
  cd 2011_0406_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO
  WPA1=HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT
  WPA2=HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT
  sed -i -e "s/$WPA1=n/$WPA1=y/g" -e "s/$WPA2=n/$WPA2=y/g" os/linux/config.mk
  sudo make && sudo make install && sudo make clean
  cd ..
  ```
- Reboot, and hopefully your wireless connection will work!
- Then open up the Downloads folder in the File Manager and delete the downloaded Ralink file/folder:

  [image]